# RSpec test passing individually, failing whole suite

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rspec, pundit

I have been having a problem with my Rails api.

The offender:

```
context 'as a publisher' do
  before { create(:invitation_post) }

  it 'shows posts whose invitations are to you' do
    authorise publisher # helper which adds an authentication token to the request headers
    get :index, params: { expand: ['invitation'] }
    expect(json_body[:data].map {|e| e[:invitation][:account] }).to all eq account.id
  end
end
```

And the error (because the response is a 403):

```
Failure/Error: expect(json_body[:data].map {|e| e[:invitation][:account] }).to all eq account.id

NoMethodError:
  undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
```

I have run `rspec` with `--bisect`, which helped me to identify a pair of examples I can run to reproduce it, which at least saves me running ~300 other tests each time. But the other example seems quite unrelated, from a different controller and test file.

I have pinpointed the point at which it fails - in my policy. I check the type of user (some single-table inheritance going on) with `user.is_a?(Publisher)`, which should return true, but in this one particular instance it doesn't. However, if I say `user.class.name == 'Publisher'`, that does return true.

I have `p`'d the user in both the test and the policy, and they appear to be completely identical.

Extra info (and I'd be happy to share more info where necessary):

- `config.use_transactional_fixtures = true` - have tried both `true` and `false` - doesn't seem to fix it.
- Test data from FactoryBot (`gem "factory_bot_rails", "~> 4.0"`)
- Have tried cleaning the db at various points with `DatabaseCleaner`, but also doesn't seem to fix
- The policy:

```
def index?
  user.is_a?(Admin) || user.is_a?(Author) || user.is_a?(Publisher)
end
```

So I suppose what I'm asking is - if the user isn't a Publisher, then what could it be? And what might I need to do to fix the test? Any help or light which could be shed would be much appreciated!

**EDIT**

The other test from the bisect:

```
it 'returns a list of invitations' do
  get :index
  expect(json_body[:data].count).to eq 4
end
```

The authorise helper:

```
def authorise(user)
  request.headers.merge!({ "Authorization" => JsonWebToken.encode(user_id: user.id) })
end
```

Comment: Could you please share the other spec which bisect returns? The one which checks the type of user? Maybe that sets something which conflicts which this test.
Additionally, could you also include the code of the helper `authorise publisher`?

Comment: Try specifing before what is that code run. `before(:example) { create(:invitation_post) }`.

Comment: why json_body[:data] could be nil? It's not see as a data missing thing. Try debugging the test case and check what is returning the data object.

Comment: @racar The response is a 403, so no data is returned, just a message saying the requested resource is forbidden